# Blender export problem

Tags: export

I tried to export my animation as PNG 0001-0250 but after the export was done files were not in png but in some unknown format.

It happens everytime i try it, FFmpeg video or any kinds of video export is not working only png or other photos.

Comment: Welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue in such way that anyone searching for a similar problem may easily find it. Use the [edit] link above, remove anything superfluous, avoid words like "*this*","*issue with*" or "*question about*". Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, answers you get depend heavily on how inviting it is. See ["*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)